# Concurrency issue with two SQLite connections in two different Threads

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using System.Data.SQLite with C#

I have

Thread 1 (UI) - writes to table1
Thread 2 (worker) writes to table1

So I have two threads writing concurrently to same database. I write my data on batches and each batch has a transaction. Batches are needed to avoid locking the database for too long so the other thread can have write access to the database.

But that doesn't work. I hoped thread1 to be able to write to the database between the transaction-batches of thread2 but that doesn't happen unless I have Thread.Sleep(100) between batches. Note having a small value for Thread.Sleep(10) doesn't work either. I understand this is related to Thread context switching but I don't understand why small amounts of Thread.Sleep doesn't do the job.

Is there way to control the priority of who acquire the lock the database, because using Thread.Sleep is bad?

P.S. It seems this is a problem even without a transactions. If I have a loop with many insert statements, the other thread cannot execute anything between insert statements if there is no Thread.Sleep

Comment: 10 milliseconds might be less than the system clock tick meaning it likely doesn't sleep at all. The documentation for `Thread.Sleep()` suggests that a particular value might do what you want, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SQlite supports true concurrent write transactions... I've used "non-exclusive" transactions on Android and they're documented (I'm writing in my own words from memory) as allowing concurrent reads while there may be a write going on.

Now more to the point... Looking at SQLite transaction docs:

https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

> Thus with a deferred transaction, the BEGIN statement itself does
>   nothing to the filesystem. Locks are not acquired until the first read
>   or write operation. The first read operation against a database
>   creates a SHARED lock and **the first write operation creates a RESERVED**
>   lock. Because the acquisition of locks is deferred until they are
>   needed, it is possible that another thread or process could create a
>   separate transaction and write to the database after the BEGIN on the
>   current thread has executed. If the transaction is immediate, then
>   **RESERVED locks are acquired on all databases** as soon as the BEGIN
>   command is executed, without waiting for the database to be used.

( emphasis - mine )

OK, so now we've learned that writing to a database requires a RESERVED lock.

Let's see what that is here:

https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#reserved_lock

> A RESERVED lock means that the process is **planning on writing** to the
>   database file at some point in the future but that it is currently
>   just reading from the file. **Only a single RESERVED lock may be active**
>   at one time, though multiple SHARED locks can coexist with a single
>   RESERVED lock. RESERVED differs from PENDING in that new SHARED locks
>   can be acquired while there is a RESERVED lock.

OK, so this confirms that SQLite requires a RESERVED lock for writing to the database, and also tells us that only a single RESERVED lock may exist at a time -> only one transaction is allowed to have write access, others will wait.

Now if you're trying to interleave writing transactions from your two threads, each thread executing multiple (granular) transactions - then here is an idea:

- Replacing Thread.Sleep with Thread.Yield

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield

This may help with the issue of "the current writing thread's Sleep didn't cause a context switch to the thread we want".

Even with Yield there are still no guarantees that the OS / runtime will switch to the thread you want, but... perhaps worth a try, and at least you won't be artificially making your code run slower.

- Given what we know about SQLite's "only one transaction is allowed to write", I'd consider the following pattern:

1 - Make a new thread whose job is to process database writes

2 - Queue up write operations to this thread from your current two threads

3 - Have the "operations" be self-contained / sufficient objects, containingf all the data they intend to write

4 - Finally, use a callback with a latch (in C# it's CountDownEvent I believe)  to know when an operation is done, so your current threads can await completion

Then you'd only have one writing thread (as far as SQlite is concerned) and still have concurrency between your two current threads.

Pseudo code:

```
// Write thread

while (item = blockingQueue.getNextItemToWrite()) {
 item.executeWrite(database)
 item.signalCompletion()
}

// Thread 1

item = new WriteItem(some data that needs to be written)
WriteThread.enqeue(item)
item.awaitCompletion()

// Thread 2 - same as Thread 1
```

Where WriteItem base class has a CountDownEvent which is 1) awaited on by awaitCompletion and 2) signaled by signalCompletion.

I'm sure there is a way to wrap this into more elegant helper classes and maybe use async / await.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried Thread.Yield but it doesn't help. About having a producer-consumer queue for writing to database. One of the reasons I didn't go that way was RESERVED locks. You can't know for sure if a query is going to need to write to the database until it actually execute. This way you can end up having db operations that will never need exclusive lock but will wait for other write operations in the queue.

Comment: But you don't have to use the "separate write thread" pattern everywhere, only where you need it...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at busy_timeout. In the ideal world, both your threads (assuming they don *not* share the connection) should be allowed to read and write at their convenience. Why bother with timing with Sleep if you can avoid it?

Next, you are correctly using transactions. Have you looked into the three different behaviours for transactions? https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

That however does not solve the issue that thread 1 might try to get a lock while thread 2 is. For this, see `PRAGMA busy_timeout`. Simply put the pragma on each connection to, say, 1000 (ms). If thread 2 has locked the database and thread 1 tries to get a lock, it will simply wait for 1000 ms until failing with a timeout error. (https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout)

Comment: I am aware of busy_timeout - This will cause exceptions for the thread waiting to obtain the lock for the database. I don't want that. I want to load balance the work between two threads